# What is name of the soundtrack used in Parasyte ep. 12 around time 14:35?

Tags: music, parasyte

There's a soundtrack used in *Parasyte* ep. 12 around time 14:35.

I tried to browse through all soundtrack but couldn't find a match.

What is the name of the soundtrack?

Answer (score 0):

"It’s the Right Time" by Daichi Miura, the ending theme of *Parasyte*.